# Import statement error in Jdeveloper for Oracle-MAF

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am using **JDeveloper 12c** and trying to create a new *Oracle MAF* Application.

In a java class inside the project I am importing `com.oracle.e1.jdemf.LoginConfiguration` which comes from a JAR file that I already included in the project.

But for some reason `JDeveloper` complains

> "Type of variable com.oracle.e1.jdemf.LoginConfiguration not found".

If I use the same import statement in a simple Java desktop application the import works fine. I am not sure what is causing it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not giving folks here much information to help you.

Comment: Did you add it to correct project? Have you tried a clean/build? What MAF / JDev version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the "classes" folder from ApplicationController and ViewController. Then Clean and Build your project from the "Build" menu of jDeveloper.